# How do you remove a UIButton/keyboard/UIAlertView from the view while json or other data is being loaded?

Tags: iphone, json, ios5, uisearchbar

I'm using a UISearchBar in my application and the problem is when I call a few json methods `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` seems to not resign the keyboard until the other methods are done loading the data. I've tried alternatively using UIAlertView and UIButtons to replace the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` function but they appear to literally freeze and stay in a "pressed down" state too. I was also wondering if this would be a reason why            `[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;` wouldn't show an activity indicator in the device's status bar.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.args = searchBar.text;
    [self grabData];
    [self fillVars];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

`[self grabData]` is where I grab the JSON data and `[self fillVars]` just fills a few things that are later used.

```
-(void)grabData{
    self.args = [self.args stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?key=%@&q=%@",baseUrl,func,apiKey,args];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error; 
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
self.matches = [json objectForKey:@"matches"];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use threading. All manipulation with your interface happens on the main thread, so when you perform a lengthy task on the main thread, the interface won't be able to update itself before the task has completed.

In a UIViewController you can do [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(grabData) withObject:self], which is a convenience method for dispatching a new queue (thread) using grand central dispact.

You could also do that manually, using the GCD API. You would do something along the lines of this:

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonQueue = dispatch_queue_create("JSON Queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(jsonQueue, ^{

    // fetch JSON data ...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // perhaps do something back on the main queue once you're done!

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm a bit familiar with GCD but I've yet to use it in an application. I'll need to look up threading a bit but I'll go try it now!

Comment: Good to hear! Better learn it ASAP, it enables you to create much richer user experiences and faster apps! Happy coding :)